# accessing DownloadStringAsync that resides in another class

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm using the webclient to do an async download from within a class. i.e

```
public void download()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.url.com"));
}
```

I'm trying to make use of the `CancelAysnc` method, I presume I'd use something like:

```
client.CancelAsync();
```

But I'd like to use it on, for instance, a click event method. Of course when I try and use the above sample it doesnt know about client. How do I get access to it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store the client object somewhere other than in a local variable. This way you would have access to it outside of your `download()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Scope...

```
WebClient client;
public void download() {
    client = new WebClient();
    // Further code...
}

public void cancel() {
    client.CancelAsync();
}
```